# which is more efficient loop.index0 or loop.index - 1

Tags: twig

for counting loop iterations in twig i've noticed that it seems down to preference in my project wether loop.index0 gets used or loop.index-1 is used.  Is there any performance difference between the two or is it actually just preference?

Comment: make no difference,as twig templates are cached into PHP scripts.A substraction is not going to affect "performances".

Comment: but objectively speaking, wouldn't that mean that index0 does one less calculation and is therefor faster?

Comment: you dont know that until you read the php code generated by twig.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so i've looked into the inner workings of twig.  it looks like that it starts off every for loop by creating an array and assigning the value of key index0 and index as 0 and 1 respectively. At the end of each loop it increments those counter, so it is slightly more efficient to just call index0 instead of index-1.